# How come `MyClass.MyStaticMethod()` doesn't work, but `Serial.begin()` does?

Tags: programming, c++, class

`MyProject.ino`:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // MyClass.MyStaticMethod();
  MyClass::MyStaticMethod();
}
```

Both uncommented lines work, but the commented (when uncommented, of course) results in this error: `expected unqualified-id before '.' token`.

Now, I know this is because of the incorrect scope-resolution. Yet, how come `Serial` manages to call static functions without the need to use `::` to correction to scope-resolution.

**How come `MyClass.MyStaticMethod()` doesn't work, but `Serial.begin()` does?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is used to call a method on a class *instance* whereas `::` is used to call a static method within a class itself.

There is no `Serial` class - `Serial` is merely an instance of the `HardwareSerial` class.

```
#if defined(UBRRH) && defined(UBRRL)
  HardwareSerial Serial(&UBRRH, &UBRRL, &UCSRA, &UCSRB, &UCSRC, &UDR);
#else
  HardwareSerial Serial(&UBRR0H, &UBRR0L, &UCSR0A, &UCSR0B, &UCSR0C, &UDR0);
#endif
```

If you want to use `.` then you have to instantiate your class and not use a static method:

```
class MyClass {
    static void myStaticMethod() {
    }
    void myMethod() {
    }
};

MyClass Fred;

// ... 

Fred.myMethod();
MyClass::myStaticMethod();
```

Comment: Ah. That was quite the misnomer since instances are usually with a lower case. I thought it was a class. :)

Comment: That is the normal way, yes - but since when have Arduino done things normally? ;)

Comment: If a newcomer (myself) is just beginning to see abnormalities, I can't imagine how many you've found. :)